# Why does Swift not allow a type conforming to a protocol to be used in an argument taking the protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, closures

Given this example code:

```
private protocol P {}
final private class X {
    private func j(j: (P) -> Void) -> Void {}
    private func jj<Z: P>(jj: (Z) -> Void) -> Void {
        j(j: jj)
    }
}
```

Swift 4 in XCode 9.1 gives this compiler error on the line `j(j: jj)`:

> Cannot convert value of type ‘(Z) -> Void’ to expected argument type
>   ‘(P) -> Void’.

Why?

Note, it seems to me that it should not give this error, because the type constraint `<Z: P>` *requires* that Z absolutely must conform to protocol P. So, there should be absolutely no reason to *convert* from Z to P, since Z already conforms to P.

Seems like a compiler bug to me...

Comment: what is an idea behind this code?

Comment: The compiler is correct – a `(Z) -> Void` is not a `(P) -> Void`. To illustrate why this is the case, let's say `String : P` & `Int : P`. Now let's substitute `Int` for `Z`. We cannot pass a `(Int) -> Void` to a `(P) -> Void`. Why? Well a `(P) -> Void` accepts *anything* that conforms to `P` – for example, we could pass in a `String`. But if that function was actually an `(Int) -> Void`, we'd be trying to pass a `String` to an `Int`, which is clearly unsound.

Comment: I disagree. Because the only thing we know about Z at runtime is that it’s a P. Whether or not it’s really an Int or String is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @CommaToast No, at *runtime* `Z` is realised with a concrete type. It is subtype of `P`, but `P` is not a subtype of it, in the same way that `String` is a subtype of `P` in my above example, but `P` is not a subtype of `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is correct – a `(Z) -> Void` is not a `(P) -> Void`. To illustrate why this is the case, let's define the following conformances:

```
extension String : P {}
extension Int : P {}
```

Now let's substitute `Int` for `Z`:

```
final private class X {

  func j(j: (P) -> Void) {
    j("foob")
  }

  func jj(jj: (Int) -> Void) {
    // error: Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Void' to expected argument
    // type '(P) -> Void'
    j(j: jj)
  }
}
```

We cannot pass an `(Int) -> Void` to a `(P) -> Void`. Why? Well a `(P) -> Void` accepts anything that conforms to `P` – for example, we could pass in a `String`. But the function that we're passing to `j` is actually an `(Int) -> Void`, so we're trying to pass a `String` to an `Int` parameter, which is clearly unsound.

If we put the generics back in, it should still be fairly clear why this cannot work:

```
final private class X {

  func j(j: (P) -> Void) {
    j("foob")
  }

  func jj<Z : P>(jj: (Z) -> Void) {
    // error: Cannot convert value of type '(Z) -> Void' to expected argument
    // type '(P) -> Void'
    j(j: jj)
  }
}

X().jj { (i: Int) in
  print(i) // What are we printing here? A String gets passed in the above implementation..
}
```

`(P) -> Void` is a function can deal with *any* `P` conforming argument. However `(Z) -> Void` is a function that can only deal with one *specific* concrete typed argument that conforms to `P` (e.g `Int` in our above example). Typing it as a function that can deal with *any* `P` conforming argument would be a lie.

Put in more technical manner, `(Z) -> Void` is not a subtype of `(P) -> Void`. Functions are [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types) with respect to their parameter types, meaning that `(U) -> Void` is a subtype of
 `(V) -> Void` if and only if `V` is a subtype of `U`. But `P` is not a subtype of `Z : P` – `Z` is a *placeholder* that is replaced at runtime with a concrete type that conforms to (so is a subtype of) `P`.

The more interesting part comes when we consider the opposite; that is, passing a `(P) -> Void` to a `(Z) -> Void`. Although the placeholder `Z : P` can only be satisfied by a concrete subtype of `P`, we cannot substitute `P` for `Z` because [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878).

Comment: In the case where Z === Any<P> then I disagree; in this case (Z)-> Void should absolutely be passable as a (P)->Void because the only thing we know about Z is its P-ness anyway! Now in a case where Z has additional constraints that the function knows about, I agree they are not the same, since Any<P,Q,R> is not just P and the function could require Q-ness and R-ness.

Comment: So it seems like a case where the compiler is forcing Any<P> to not be passable as P, just because Any<P,Q,R> is not passable as P. Which is to throw out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: Nonetheless since your answer explains the (partially flawed) rationale behind the current Swift compiler, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @CommaToast "*In the case where Z === Any<P>*" – that's just one case through; the implementation of the generic function doesn't know what `Z` is at compile time (but `Z` can't be `P` anyway because protocols don't always conform to themselves). This is just as illegal: `func foo<T : P>(_ x: T, _ p: P) { let y: T = p }`. Remember that Swift generics aren't like C++ templates; the compiler doesn't create individual specialised implementations for each substitution of the generic placeholder(s), it only emits one implementation (though it can specialise as an optimisation).